# Javascript array output in table lined up

Tags: javascript

I deleted my previous post by accident, so I need to post it again.

I have a code which works very nicely and I had great help here. The only thing is that the array **players** output are not very nicely lined up with each other in a table.
Having a fixed width will only line up the numbers, but doesn't line them out like a table does.

My question is, how can this code (**array players output**) be modified to have it nicely lined up?

```
<html>    
<head>    
<title>Lotto van Terwijn</title>    
<body>    
<p><img src="../lotto/images/terwijn.png" width="547" height="188"></p>    
<style type="text/css">    
      body {    
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
        color: #000000;    
        background-color: #FFFFFF;    
      }    
      .name {    
        color: #000000;    
        font-weight: bold;    
        margin-right: 0.5em;    
      }    
      .picks, .picks * {    
        display: inline;    
        margin: 0;    
        padding: 0;    
        list-style-type: none;    
      }    
      .picks * {    
        margin: auto 0.25em;    
                               color: Yellow;    
      }    
      .win { color: #ffcc00; font-weight: bold }    
      .loss { color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold }    
      .drawNum, #Draws H3 {    
          margin-bottom: 0;    
      }    
    </style>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
<div id="players"></div>
<div id="draws"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript">

var players = {
Joop   : ["6","8","16","18","26","28","32","36","38","41"],
Marijke: ["7","10","14","18","24","29","30","34","39","40"],
Michel : ["4","5","11","16","21","27","33","36","42","44"],
Mario  : ["6","9","18","25","32","35","39","40","43","45"],
Diana  : ["2","6","8","17","22","23","33","36","42","45"],
Agnes  : ["3","5","10","15","26","29","32","37","41","44"],
Chris  : ["5","7","8","9","11","12","16","28","30","32"],
Jeannette: ["1","2","4","7","8","11","13","28","30","38"],
Wieger: ["1","2","3","7","10","13","14","22","23","27"],
Anita: ["6","13","15","17","21","26","32","33","43","45"],
Thea: ["1","3","5","7","10","17","19","20","22","38"],
Danny: ["3","7","11","15","22","28","32","37","40","43"],
Cindy: ["2","4","16","18","21","24","33","38","41","44"],
Hanneke: ["1","3","4","12","18","21","25","30","36","40"],
Willem: ["3","9","17","21","27","33","35","39","41","42"]
};

var draws = [ {

when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 08-08-2009',
picks:[2, 13, 15, 18, 21, 41]
},

{
when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 15-08-2009',
picks:[6, 19, 24, 25, 35, 37]
},

{
when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 22-08-2009',
picks:[8, 17, 23, 26, 37, 42]
}
];

var buildPlayers = function(){
var cont = $("#players");
for(player in players){
var html = ["<div>","<span class='name'>"+player+"</span>", "<ol class='picks'>"];
for(var i = 0; i < players[player].length; i++){
html.push("<li class='loss pick_"+players[player][i]+"'>"+players[player][i]+"</li>");
}

html.push("</ol>","</div>");
cont.append(html.join(""));
}
};

var buildDraws = function(){
var cont = $("#draws");
for(var i = 0; i < draws.length; i++){
var html = ["<div class='draw'>","<h4 class='drawNum'>Trekking "+(i+1)+"</h3>","<div class='date'>"+draws[i].when+"</div>","<ol class='picks'>"];

for(var j = 0; j < draws[i].picks.length; j++) {
      var img = '<img src="http://www.lotto.nl/static/images/ballen/lotto/l'
                     + draws[i].picks[j]
                     + '.jpg" alt="'
                     + draws[i].picks[j]
                     + '" />';
      html.push("<li>"+img+"</li>");
      showWin(draws[i].picks[j]);
  }



html.push("</ol>","</div>");
cont.append(html.join(""));
}
};

var showWin = function(winNum){
$(".pick_"+winNum).removeClass("loss").addClass("win");
};

$(function(){
buildPlayers();
buildDraws();
});
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ Darko Z, you edited the body tag and image right :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript array output in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317079/javascript-array-output-in-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<div id="players"></div>
<div id="draws"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

 var players = {
    Joop   : ["6","8","16","18","26","28","32","36","38","41"],
    Marijke: ["7","10","14","18","24","29","30","34","39","40"],
    Michel : ["4","5","11","16","21","27","33","36","42","44"],
    Mario  : ["6","9","18","25","32","35","39","40","43","45"],
    Diana  : ["2","6","8","17","22","23","33","36","42","45"],
    Agnes  : ["3","5","10","15","26","29","32","37","41","44"],
    Chris  : ["5","7","8","9","11","12","16","28","30","32"],
    Jeannette: ["1","2","4","7","8","11","13","28","30","38"],
    Wieger: ["1","2","3","7","10","13","14","22","23","27"],
    Anita: ["6","13","15","17","21","26","32","33","43","45"],
    Thea: ["1","3","5","7","10","17","19","20","22","38"],
    Danny: ["3","7","11","15","22","28","32","37","40","43"],
    Cindy: ["2","4","16","18","21","24","33","38","41","44"],
    Hanneke: ["1","3","4","12","18","21","25","30","36","40"],
    Willem: ["3","9","17","21","27","33","35","39","41","42"]
},

draws = [
    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 08-08-2009',
          picks:[2, 13, 15, 18, 21, 41]
    },

    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 15-08-2009',
      picks:[6, 19, 24, 25, 35, 37]
    },

    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 22-08-2009',
      picks:[8, 17, 23, 26, 37, 42]
    }
];

var buildPlayers = function(){
    var cont = $("#players"), table = $('<table></table>');
    for( player in players ){
    if ( players.hasOwnProperty( player ) ) {
        var tr = $('<tr><th>' + player + '</th></tr>').appendTo(table),
            len = players[player].length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var td = $('<td/>').text( players[player][i] )
            .appendTo ( tr );
        }

        cont.append( table );
    }
    }
};

var buildDraws = function(){
    var cont = $("#draws");
    for(var i = 0; i < draws.length; i++){
    var html = ["<div class='draw'>","<h4 class='drawNum'>Trekking "+(i+1)+"</h3>","<div class='date'>"+draws[i].when+"</div>","<ol class='picks'>"];

    for(var j = 0; j < draws[i].picks.length; j++) {
        var img = '<img src="http://www.lotto.nl/static/images/ballen/lotto/l'
        + draws[i].picks[j]
        + '.jpg" alt="'
        + draws[i].picks[j]
        + '" />';
        html.push("<li>"+img+"</li>");
        showWin(draws[i].picks[j]);
    }



    html.push("</ol>","</div>");
    cont.append(html.join(""));
    }
};

var showWin = function(winNum){
    $(".pick_"+winNum).removeClass("loss").addClass("win");
};

$(function(){
    buildPlayers();
    buildDraws();
    });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: There seems to be some sort of error in my code where the first table row doesn't correctly get created/appended, that's odd.. heh.

Comment: I think it has to do something with the initial insert of the first row in a table.

Comment: @Meder, thank you for your quick reply, when I implement your code I get a blank page. Did I do something wrong? I overwrite the code from
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>

to

</script>

I left the rest intact.

Comment: There was a console.log declaration which I was using for testing, try removing it if you copied it - sorry about that.

Comment: @Meder, the code did it's job, I had to make some minor changes to have the names aligned to the left. The only thing that doesn't work are the colors lime and red for the numbers. This part is critical for the function of the website.